# What source of entropy can I use with Apache on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache, ssl

The SSLRandomSeed directive expects either a file of the type /dev/random or an executable that outputs random bytes. There are functions to provide entropy on Windows, if I were writing a program, but is there just a source ready to use? Or one I can download off the web?

Comment: @cypherabe: I don't think this is a duplicate, because that is about what sources of entropy exist. Whereas this is about how I can get at that entropy in a format suitable for Apache.

Comment: okay, I removed my "possible dublicate" comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd appreciate review by someone who knows more about security pitfalls than I do, but here's what I came up with to solve my problem. (It's also hosted as a snippet with a license and a compiled binary [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/MartinEden/yqR7p)).

```cs
// To compile run:
// csc entropy.cs
// If csc is not on your path, it is probably somewhere like C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Entropy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numberOfArgs = args.Length;
            int bytesToOutput = 1024;
            if (numberOfArgs > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too many arguments. Expected either none, or the number of bytes to output");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
            else if (numberOfArgs == 1)
            {
                bytesToOutput = int.Parse(args[0]);
            }

            byte[] output = new byte[bytesToOutput];
            var provider = RNGCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
            provider.GetBytes(output);
            using (var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput())
            {
                stdout.Write(output, 0, bytesToOutput);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're willing to trust your security to that code (which comes with no warranty) then grab the binary version or compile the code yourself, and copy it to your apache directory. Then add these lines to your SSL conf:

```
SSLRandomSeed startup exec:entropy.exe 512
SSLRandomSeed connect exec:entropy.exe 512
```